# Creating a property wrapper with an inherited wrappedValue property

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

#### TL;DR

Is it possible for a `@propertyWrapper` to have an inherited `wrappedValue` property when it conforms to a `protocol` that already defines it?

If we do not explicitly specify the `wrappedValue` property, then we get the error:

> Property wrapper type does not contain a non-static property named 'wrappedValue'

#### Example

Suppose we have a model like:

```swift
struct User: Decodable {
    @DefaultFalse var isVerified: Bool
    ...
}
```

where `@DefaultFalse` is a `@propertyWrapper` that defaults the property to `false` if it is decoded as `null`.

To achieve this we could design a *generalized* `protocol` like:

```swift
protocol Default: Decodable {
    associatedtype Value: Decodable

    static var defaultValue: Value { get }
    var value: Value? { get set }
}

extension Default {

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value ?? Self.defaultValue }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if container.decodeNil() {
            value = nil
        } else {
            value = try container.decode(Value.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Where `@Default` is a `protocol` that could default any `Decodable` value (not just `Bool`). Our `@DefaultFalse` implementation might look like:

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct DefaultFalse: Default {
    static let defaultValue = false
    var value: Bool?
}
```

but this errors with the above.

I understand in this example it would be simpler to just use `Bool?` and fallback with `isVerified ?? false` - but I've attempted to simplify a use case.

#### Other

I found a similar [question](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-it-allowed-to-inherit-a-property-wrapper-class/28695) on Swift Forums without an answer at this time.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.